# Perform segue from inside a popover

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I want to replace the contents of a popover without dismissing the popover

my probelm is, if i use UINavigationViewController as the root of the popover inner view controller, the next view controller that I display, takes up the whole size of the screen minus the margins i gave it.

I want the next contents in the popover to be the same size as the original

How can I do that?

Comment: Decrease the xib size of next view controller and try(If you are using any xib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting    `self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = sizeOfThePopover;` for the view controller you want to add to popover. Or you can use `self.preferredContentSize = sizeOfThePopover;` available from iOS7

Comment: I did that... my popover content is a webview, and it at first displays the size i want, and then when its done loading, it expands full screen, which is what i dont want to happen